# Button click event running endlessly in my NodeJs app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am learning NodeJs from [a LinkedIn Course](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/learning-node-js-2017/types-of-data-frameworks) in which I am trying to create a simple chat app using Express+NodeJs for server-side and some html for client.

The button in my client page is triggering click event endlessly and I couldn't fault it. I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

Server.Js

```
    let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

let messages = [
    {name: "Parth", message: "Hello"},
    {name: "Nihal", message: "Hi"}
];

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    res.send(messages);
});

app.post('/message', (req, res) => {
    messages.push(req.body);
    io.emit('message', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    console.log(`Message posted from ${req.body.name}.`);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("A user has connected");
});

var server = http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("The server is liestening on port ", server.address().port);
});
```

Client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Send Message</h1>
        <br/>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
        <br/>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSend">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="divMessages">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    let socket = io();
    $(() => {
        $("#btnSend").on('click', (e) => {
            var message = {name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()};
            postMessage(message);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        getMessages();
    });

    socket.on('message', addMessage);

    function addMessage(message){
        $("#divMessages").append(`<h4>${message.name}</h4> <p>${message.message}</p>`)
    }

    function getMessages(){
        $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                addMessage(element);
            });
        })
    }

    function postMessage(message){
        console.log("Posting...");
        $.post('http://localhost:3000/message', message);
    }
    
</script>
```

I have created a repo here - https://github.com/septst/chat-app

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here, please? Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything that would create multiple click events. If you put `console.log("click");` in the click handler, do you see it repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, it doesn’t look obvious. But really puzzling. The “posting…” log in postMessage function is going on endlessly.

Comment: Is there any other code that calls `postMessage()`? I asked you to add a log message to the click function, so we can distinguish the different ways it's called.